# Building maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have created a simple maven project using eclipse. I am getting the following error:

> Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:1.0 from any of the configured repositories.
>
> Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0
>
> Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
>
> Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org

I have set maven path in environment variable. While I run `mvn --version` from cmd it's giving proper maven version and message.

Comment: Sitting behind a proxy/firewall ? You should start with Maven projects on command line and not within Eclipse.

Comment: thanks khmarbaise for reply.There is no any way to run maven project from eclipse.